# How to determine if checkbox is different from its initial checked state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can use `defaultChecked` to determine if what the initial state of checkbox is, but how can I determine if one of these has changed from the default?

I need to set a variable so I can manipulate something else based on the result of this, this is what I currently have:

```
// This checks if a checkbox has changed from being initially checked
$isModified = $(this).find('input')[0].defaultChecked !== $(this).find('input').prop('checked') ? true : false
```

[EDIT] I need to check if a checkbox has changed from it's default state regardless of whether it was checked initially or not.

This is what I thought might work (but doesn't):

```
$isModified = $this.find('input')[0].defaultChecked !== $this.find('input')[0].defaultChecked ? true : false
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

[EDIT]
After a lot of very helpful.. help. Here is my solution that is fired when there is a change event on one of the inputs:

```
$('#input-parent').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this),
        isModified
    ;

    $this.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( !isModified) {
            isModified = $this[0].defaultChecked !== $this[0].checked;
        }
    });

    if ( isModified ) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }

});
```

Comment: just fyi, you don't need to prefix variables with a $ in Javascript

Comment: also fyi: Its common to prefix *jQuery objects* with `$` to distinguish them, but not normal variables like bools or strings etc.

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, I usually prefix jQuery object vars with `$`, not sure why added it to this var...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your example you are comparing `defaultChecked` to `defaultChecked` property. You should compare `defaultChecked` and `checked` properties.

```
$isModified = $this.find('input')[0].defaultChecked !== $this.find('input')[0].checked;
```

Comment: Hello sir,  What's difference between the default Checked and checked property?